# How to make hover using jquery without CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created some div dynamically with the class name ".pics" like below

```
$(MyJson).each(function (obj) {
            $("#GalleryPics").append("<div class='pics'><a href='#' class='delete'>some</a><a href='" + MyJson[obj].ImageURL + "' rel='lightbox-journey' class='delete'><img src='" + MyJson[obj].ImageURL + "' width='150' height='150' /></a></div>");
        });
```

Using this above code, i can get some images inside each div with ".pics " class name. Now i need to do that if i want to delete any image, i should show a delete button with its action on image hover.. ".delete" is the class which i want to show the delete button there.. How can i achieve it..

Note:

I have tried some CSS codes and .hover(function(){ too, but i couldn't achieve it.Please help me as soon as you can..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a JQuery `.hover()` function that does a good job.
This **does** use CSS for showing and hiding using a transition. you can easily change that to JQuery's `show` and `hide` functions if you like, though IMO plain CSS gives you more flexibility.

```
var pics = $(".pics");
var deleteThis = $(".delete");
pics.hover(function () 
{
    deleteThis.addClass("show")
}, 
function () 
{
    deleteThis.removeClass("show")
})
```

and then in the CSS,

```
.delete {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    color: white;
    transition: all .2s ease;
}

.delete.show {
    top: 0px;   
}
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewmess/3VpY6/1/)

Comment: Wow.. My Perfect Solution it is.. Thank you very much!! But only thing is i need to add "rel:lightbox-journey" not in image attribute, i should place in anchor tag and inside the anchor tag only, these image should come..

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to do what I think you're asking about. the `<img>` is now inside its own `<a>` element with `"rel:lightbox-journey" ` . You're very welcome!

Comment: Thank a lot sir.. I was struct in this issue for a long time.. You helped me.. Thanks once again.. Finally i got a packed solution from you.. Can i have your email ID please? need to ask some doubts regarding this?

Comment: Please see my account for contact info - but remember that if you have additional questions that others can benefit from viewing, the best thing would always be to post a new question!

Answer (score 0):

**Jquery Hover**

```
$(foo).mouseover(function(){
    //Do hover action
});

$(baz).mouseleave(function(){
    //Undo hover action
});
```

**CSS hover**

```
foo:hover{
    //Do hover
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xz2hh/)**

Comment: Thanks.. It is working. But it is not completely hide, it is blinking.. How can i resolve that..

Comment: If you are using my Jquery code then the element for mouseleave should probaly not be the same as mouseenter. If they are the same then it will blink. Try setting the element for mouseleave to be the parent element.